# graph editor motion curves in 3D view

Tags: keyframes, graph-editor, bezier-curves

Is there any way to get the graph editor curves in the 3D view? I know I can calculate motion paths for select bones, but it would be way easier to edit motion paths if I could just edit them as one 3D bezier the 3D view the same way you edit normal curves in the 3D view. If it's not built into 2.79 or 2.80 are there any plug ins for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create a path from an existing object animation?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52830/is-it-possible-to-create-a-path-from-an-existing-object-animation)

Comment: Also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117062/fcurve-handles-to-3d-b%c3%a9zier-spline-control-points