# How to see a path transform graph for animated object

Tags: path, graph-editor

I just want to see the transform graph for the selected object. For example I want to select one small cube and, after animating it, I want to display the path for this cube in a graph. Like on this image:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the motion paths section of the properties window you can calculate the motion path for the selected object.

[image]

For 2.8:

[image]

Press the "calculate button"

A graph of the movement and keyframes will show on the 3d Viewport.

[image]

Note that any changes on the animation or keyframes will not update autmatically, you need to hit the "update" path every time you make any changes.

For more precise control on animation use the graph editor.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Cetagon. Will be handy!

Comment: Possibly Related (going by other answer and image in question) https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117062/fcurve-handles-to-3d-b%c3%a9zier-spline-control-points