# I Want To Observe X Y Z Di̇splacement Graph

Tags: path, graph-editor

I want to see path transform graph. For example: I want to observe displacement in X Y and Z direction in the graph.

I want to display for example graph of path which is in the image.

[image]

Comment: Please don't ask the same questionmultiple times. Read [what should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to see a path transform graph for animated object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135652/how-to-see-a-path-transform-graph-for-animated-object)