# Is there any way to turn coordinates into curve?

Tags: camera, bezier-curves, keyframes

I recorded fly camera movement, so I got keyframes with coordinates.
Is there any way to turn the camera coordinates in keyframes into curve?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117062/fcurve-handles-to-3d-b%c3%a9zier-spline-control-points

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52830/is-it-possible-to-create-a-path-from-an-existing-object-animation   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52830/is-it-possible-to-create-a-path-from-an-existing-object-animation

Answer (score -1):

yes,the way I've found how is:

1: Turn auto key on and record your camera movement using free roam.

2: now create a mesh (has to be a mesh, cube etc) and put the "copy location"constraint on it and select the camera as the object. They should now do the same movement. (minus rotation as curves don't use that anyway).

3: Select the cube and in the 3d view go to object > animation > bake

4: In the bake settings make sure visual keying is turned on, select your frames etc and hit bake. I suggest a high frame rate of 1 step for now.

5: you'll need the blender addon "BTracer" included in blender. Go to the "create" tab in 3d view toolbar, and where it says "available tools" select "mesh follow".

6: Select "object" from the four options and your frame step / curve settings you want. Then hit "Run!"

You can decimate the keyframes later using the "simplify curves+" blender add on (search for "simplify" then move mouse left or right to change the amount. So you don't have a million points of adjustment.

It's pretty easy once you do it, pretty fast.

Done